# Cannot read property 'pushState' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, url-routing

I have this simple configuration for the React Router. I have another one with basically wrapping with  ... , which works. But this one doesn't (of course I tried to use with different implementations like suggested in the answers of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router) and many others.

The console error is the title of this post.
Using ES6, and react-router v.1 with hash-based routing.

I read **a lot** of articles, too unnecessary for simple routing to be implemented, and almost hating react and react-router now. Please help.

```
    componentWillReceiveProps() {
       this.contextTypes = {
          history: React.PropTypes.object
       }
    },
    _handleRoute(e) {
       e.preventDefault()
       this.history.pushState(null, `/somepath`);
    },
    render() {
        return(
          <div onClick={this._handleRoute}>
            Some Content.
          </div>
        );
      }
```

or:

```
render() {
        return(
          <div>
            <Link to={`/somepath`}> link </Link>
          </div>
        );
      }
```

Comment: If you're using es2015 `class` syntax, try `this._handleRoute.bind(this)`, with [ref](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#autobinding).

Comment: Did you install and update all dependencies?

Comment: Which ones do you mean specifically? I have all that is there with the component working has.. @fuyushimoya It didn't work :/

Comment: Maybe you can post the whole component, with the unnecessary parts removed?

Comment: Actually, component is pretty simple. The details is that this component represents objects that are on a googlemaps view. Also, I'm using hash-based routing.

Comment: At first glance seems that the context of `_handleRoute` is not the same than the context in which `history` is defined but without further information it is difficult to say...

Comment: @HenryVonfire Where shall I define the history context? I updated the que with the relevant code.

Comment: You should use `this.context.history` instead of `this.history`

Comment: I tried that already, not working...

Comment: Well, aham, location.hash = 'mypath' works like a charm. Love old school JS.

Comment: Well are you using hash or pushState :/

Comment: Here in doc https://github.com/rackt/react-router they say you should install History as dependendency:  `Note that you need to also install the history package since it is a peer dependency of React Router and won't automatically be installed for you in npm 3+.` Did you try that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**React Router v1:**

There's the pushState method in history object made for this.

First the component assigned for router has to give the child component the pushState method as a function prop:

```
//Router Component
render ()
  return (
    <SomeComponent changeRoute={this.props.history.pushState}
  )
```

Then, in the Component that I want to change route in a function, I simply do:

```
//SomeComponent
onClick() {
  this.props.changeRoute(null, 'somepath', {query: "something"});
}
```

**React Router v.2**

```
import {browserHistory} from 'react-router';

//SomeComponent

browserHistory.push('somepath');
```

Answer (score 2):

The error you're getting suggests that `context.history` is not defined.

Most likely, this is because you're not rendering a `<Router>` or equivalent component at the top level. Try starting with some of the examples provided with React Router and modifying them to suit your specific use case.

Answer (score 0):

It's been too long since I've asked this q, but I thought I'd answer the most simple and basic answer that I've found it to be working, which is:

```
location.hash: '/some-route?sheeps=black';
```

If anybody has a better, more 'React way' of doing it; please answer. I still don't mark this answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Update Answer with New **React Rout and Update React** To day date: **07/29/2017**

All Version:

```
"history": "^4.6.3",
"react": "^15.6.1",
"react-dom": "^15.6.1",
"react-router": "^4.1.2",
"react-router-dom": "^4.1.2",
"webpack": "^3.3.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^2.5.1"
```

MY Rout Look LIke it...

```
 import {BrowserRouter,Route,Link} from 'react-router-dom'; // for BrowserRouter rout

<BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Layout}></Route>
            <Route path='/about' name="about" component={about}> </Route>
            <Route path='/protfolio' name="protfolio" component={protfolio}></Route>
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter >
```

More details about New [**React Rout Quick Start**](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router)

For **Link** View or nav View

```
    <Link to="/about">Check rout link protfolio</Link>
     <Link to="/protfolio">Check rout link protfolio</Link>
   <button onClick={this.navigate.bind(this)}>button binf</button>
```

**Final Look:**

```
   navigate(){
        this.props.history.replace('/', null);
    }
```

if take `console.log(this.props.history);` Then your Browser console you get it...

**`push:function push(path, state)`**

So can not Use it like `this.props.history.replace(null, '/');`

Because here the path is null this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

in `react-router-dom v6` you have to use **useNavigate()**

like this:

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const navigate = useNavigate();

navigate(`/cart/${id}?qty=${qty}`)
```

this way you can navigate to another url