# Prevent persisting of state when using history.push()

Tags: reactjs, react-router, browser-history, react-router-v4

I'm using `this.props.history.push('/', { signOut: true })` for when user clicks a button.

It does work, but even though I refresh `/` the data is always persisted. How can I make it so it only happens once (when a user clicks a button), then I'm able to handle the logic :)

Are there any other ways to do this? Would love the help ;c

Comment: Click this Link [A react Rout answer it may be Help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33674650/cannot-read-property-pushstate-of-undefined) To find to the solution. Just take a Look my answer for you Solution